# Python 2 bytes binary array conversion to interger or float

Tags: python, arrays, matlab

I read a binary array from a digital scope, but then I can't do anything with the binary array.
in Matlab this is a simple job:
Data is the Array ( 2 bytes per sample, binary format)
it can be converted to 16bit integer with this instruction

```
 Data = typecast(uint8(Data),'int16'); %convert data to int16
```

and then to float using

```
 Data = double(Data); %covert data to double to be able to perform math
```

In Python i have the same array called `dataIn` , read from an instrument. I cannot find a way to convert the binary array into a 16 bit array of integers, and then to a vector of real values.

If anyone has solved this issue I would appreciate some help. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `numpy`, this is pretty easy:

```
data = numpy.frombuffer(bytes_data, dtype=numpy.uint16)
data = numpy.array(data, dtype=float)
```

Comment: never mind...I have seen the solution posted while i was writing. Thank you so much, it works just as expected. I was looking in the wrong section (struc and array conversion). I will now read the numpy related documentation.

Comment: in Python 3.7 I was getting an error, and had to modify the command

Comment: In the modern world, I think the numpy API has changed to push people to use `np.frombuffer` instead of `np.fromstring` -- I've updated the answer to reflect that.